# How to concatenate a char onto a string in Rust?

Tags: string, char, rust

I have tried using the `to_string` method on the char but this returns a `&str` when I need a `String`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe i got horribly confused somewhere. Chronium's answer is perfect however.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Using [`String::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push) method is the easiest method:

```
let mut a_string = String::from("Hello World");
a_string.push('!');
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `format!`:

```
fn main() {
   let s = String::from("March");
   // example 1
   let s1 = format!("{}!", s);
   // example 2
   let s2 = format!("{}{}", s, '!');
   // print
   println!("{} {}", s1, s2);
}
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html